# Sort after Converting Object Name to Autonumber

Tags: custom-object, data-loader, list, list-view, import

We are trying to insert all of our historical quote data to a custom object "Quote". In doing so, we want to conserve the existing quote number that was generated in our legacy Access database but continue to generate numbers going forward.

Resources online have suggested to simply upsert the data with the Quote Name set to be a text field and then convert this to an autonumber afterwards. The problem we are finding with this is that the list views appear to conserve the sorting funtionality of a text field rather than a number field.

Ex:

1, 10, 2, 20 ...

Rather than:

1, 2, 10, 20 ...

Has anyone ever experienced this challenge before or have any suggestions as to how one might overcome this?